# How can I calculate if a DBMS is going to have concurrency problems?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, model-view-controller

Pretty much what the question states. I have developed an online voting system for my work. It can have as much as 1000 persons voting at the same time, but that's so very unlikely to happen.

Let's say that 5000 people can vote for many different `options` depending on where they live. Assuming that 1000 employees live in `A`, then they can only vote for `W`, `X` or `Y`; meanwhile 1500 `employees` live in `B` and can only vote for `Z`, `T` and `V`; and so on.

---

To check for potential concurrency problems should I investigate the hardware of the server and the connections it currently has?

---

should I not worry?

---

should I treat this as a potential concurrency problem and treat it as such?

---

There may be other possibilities to consider and I'm definitely opened to them.

---

There is many more details about it, so I can answer questions that clarify this poorly explained functioning of the system, if they are strictly related to the concurrency problem of the question.

Comment: Unless they all vote at 09:00:00 and zero nano seconds on monday morning, I would not worry too much, Thats what proper DBMS's are built to cope with and sort out automagically for you

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I thought